# FTP Client not accepting welcome message

Tags: ftp, response, wireshark, filezilla

Alright so, I was developing a FTP Server on port 2121 as apart of a much larger project.

Right now the client connects and all fine
The server sends a 202 response code to the client (Which means continue pretty much)

I've wiresharked the client and can confirm the packet is going through.

Curious to see what FileZilla did, I wiresharked their server response and then sent the same, needless to say it didn't work, showing that it isn't the 220 response but something else, which I am unaware about.

---

Solution Found :: add \r\n to the end of queries

Comment: Alright so, needless to say ... What's your question???

Comment: Can you please clarify? Like adding the exchanged messages to the question, and actually ask a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this along time ago and have since fixed the issue, I am answering it incase anyone searches and has a similar problem.

The issue is caused by not including a carriage return at the end of requests, make sure you do that :)